# Using Dlink DWM 156 with Ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, usb, modem

I have recently a new USB modem, named DLink DWM-156. But I am not able to connect internet via this on Ubuntu.
I have read and applied various solutions available online, but none works.

I'll explain things as much as I can so a solution can be figured out.

This modem do have its Linux drivers. First I tried to connect it without installing them,  with the help of `Sakis3g`. But Sakis failed in locating device. `lsusb` showed device with `2001:a706` ids. But it was not being shown anywhere in devices.

Then I mounted it, extracted .deb drivers and installed it. One thing to note is that after installing it, gdebi was not showing options for reinstall or remove, though when I checked it in Synaptics, it was showing there as installed.

Anyhow, after installing drivers, when I replug modem, it gets detected in devices but as CD-ROM. `lsusb` showed `2001:7001` as ids, which mean modem has switched.

Now the question is, if it has switched then why its not show showing up as a modem? I tried `usbserial-driver-bind.sh` in terminal but of no use.

Sakis3g detects it now but while connecting it shows error like `ttyusb0 is presently occupied by PID xxxx cat`.

I have tested modem on windows and it works like charm there. What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

in that sense, just use network manager(nm) to connect your modem over mobile broad band which is the default.it also  make you use modem manager gui to send sms,USSD,etc

eject the driver cd of your modem as soon as you plug in the modem from the terminal or DISKS. thats all your modem will be seen in the nm after 10s as new connection.
configure it & use it.

network manager do not detects your d-link-156 automatic using usb mode switch in 12.04/13.10 as it is a newer one to market. just you need to add your device id to usb mode switch .